# gorilla handlers write to file

Tags: http, go

```
import (
    "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
)

func main(){
    ...

    err := http.ListenAndServe(":9000", access_log(r))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("HTTP server: ", err)
    }
}

func access_log(r http.Handler) http.Handler {
    f, err := os.OpenFile("log/access.log", os.O_CREATE | os.O_WRONLY | os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic("Access log: ", err)
    }

    return handlers.LoggingHandler(io.Writer(f), r)
}
```

The file is created but nothing is written to the file on each request

## update

This works when the output is written to `os.Stdout`

```
func access_log(r http.Handler) http.Handler {
    /*f, err := os.OpenFile("log/access.log", os.O_CREATE | os.O_WRONLY | os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic("Access log: ", err)
    }

    return handlers.LoggingHandler(io.Writer(f), r)*/

    return handlers.LoggingHandler(os.Stdout, r)
}
```

## update II

```
func main(){
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())

    r := mux.NewRouter()

    www := r.Host("secure.domain.com").Subrouter()
    www.HandleFunc("/", Handler_www)

    api := r.Host("api.domain.com").Subrouter()
    api.HandleFunc("/", Handler_api)

    err := http.ListenAndServe(":9000", access_log(r))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("HTTP server: ", err)
    }
}

func access_log(r http.Handler) http.Handler {
    f, err := os.OpenFile("log/access.log", os.O_CREATE | os.O_WRONLY | os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic("Access log: ", err)
    }

    return handlers.LoggingHandler(f, r)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try starting from a working example, as described in "[Making and Using HTTP Middleware](http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/making-and-using-middleware)":

```
package main

import (
  "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
  "net/http"
  "os"
)

func main() {
  finalHandler := http.HandlerFunc(final)

  logFile, err := os.OpenFile("server.log", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  http.Handle("/", handlers.LoggingHandler(logFile, finalHandler))
  http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}

func final(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  w.Write([]byte("OK"))
}
```

The `handlers.LoggingHandler()` uses the file directly, not `io.Writer(f)`.

In your case:

```
return handlers.LoggingHandler(f, r)
```

Comment: @clarkk the example above should show that you should use `f` directly, not  `io.Writer(f)`, when `calling handlers.LoggingHandler()`

Comment: the filesize of serverlog.log is 144 byte but its empty when opening it.. (windows > notepad)

Comment: @clarkk did you use `return handlers.LoggingHandler(f, r)`?

Comment: @clarkk and can you try with notepad++ instead of notepad?

Comment: @clarkk did you use a code similar to `http.Handle("/", handlers.LoggingHandler(f, finalHandler))
  http.ListenAndServe(":9000", nil)`?

Comment: @clarkk try using the code above: `http.Handle("/", handlers.LoggingHandler(f, finalHandler)) http.ListenAndServe(":9000", nil)`